# Where are the DNS settings for my Google domain?

Tags: google-workspace, domain, dns

I purchased a domain through Google but I can't find the DNS settings page anymore. It used to be available from the control panel but not anymore. How do I access the DNS settings?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question for end-users of web applications.

Comment: Arguably the question is about using Google's DNS _control panel_, which _is_ a web application. So I'm voting to leave it open (under doubt).

Comment: I would place this question in the same category as something like "how do I change the password of my router?", which involves a web interface, but is not strictly about an end-user concern with a specific web application.  Happy to consider other opinions and re-open if need be.  However, since it has an answer and will not be deleted by the system, I'd say that it serves as a good precedent for future questions of this type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login to your account.

On Tab Domain Settings, there's a sub section called "Domains"

There, you click on "Advanced Domain settings", which will take you to your domain services(ex: godaddy) console.

I am not sure if you could change the DNS settings right from your Google Apps console. I never saw that option. As far as I remember, this option was available at the GoDaddy's console page.

Comment: That's correct - I did this just yesterday.   One more thing though.   Nick says that he purchased his domain though Google - was this from Sites or Blogger, by any chance?   Now that there is no longer a free edition of Apps, there backdoor route (buying a domain via Blogger) works but has some twitches.   If you did buy it thru Blogger, then you need to log in to the domain with an admin user called BloggerHelper, after firsly re-setting it's password.